# How can i fix this ue5 crash

Tags: crash, unreal-engine5

Assertion failed: WorldPartition->World == World [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Editor\WorldPartitionEditor\Private\WorldPartition\SWorldPartitionEditor.cpp] [Line: 73]

i need a way to fix this.
It happens everytkme i want to start this ue5 priject

I tried restoring an old save file but it didnt work and nothig ive tried so far worked.
This has been going on for about 3 to 4 days now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, I realize it’s been a while, but maybe this will help others.
I got the same problem.
What I remember I moved the map file to another folder.
This map was in the settings of the project as the start.

It helped me delete the folder Config inside the project, after that I was able to start the project, but the map died and could not restore it.

The default map settings themselves are in the file Config/DefaultEngine.ini

Look for:
GameDefaultMap=/Game/MyGame/Maps/MENU.MENU
EditorStartupMap=/Game/MyGame/Maps/MapStarter.MapStarter

Maybe changing them will help with the launch of the project. =)